# What is the opposite of symbol-function?

Tags: reflection, lisp, common-lisp

While `(symbol-function '1+)` gives the function bound to symbol `#<function 1+>`, what is the way to get the symbol a particular function is bound to? Something like: `(function-symbol #'1+)` => `'1+`? Or will I have to search for it myself in the current package? (hope not...)

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is the prototype (but it doesn't work because I get errors if function is not defined but is bound - which I don't really understand)

```
(defun function-symbol (searched)
  (loop for f being the symbols in *package*
       do (format t "f: ~s~&" f)
       when (and (fboundp f)
         (eq searched (symbol-function f)))
       collect f))
```

**MORE EDIT:**
It appears that `symbol-value` was throwing, removing that check seem to work, but I would still like to find out a better way.

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking... it's the same as asking "which variable is 17?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your Common Lisp supports it, there is the ANSI Common Lisp function `FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION`. Its third value is the name.

Using LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 95 > (defun my-foo () )
MY-FOO

CL-USER 96 > (nth-value 2 (function-lambda-expression #'my-foo))
MY-FOO
```